# How to center column class in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie bootstrap 3. I use some html code like this

```
<ul class="row>
 <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></li>
 <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></li>
 ..
</ul>
```

how can i center the li without known the number of the li tag.
thanks you!

Comment: try like ul.row li{text-align:center;}

Comment: What do you mean by `center column class`? Would you like to center align the text inside all li items? If so, apply "text-center" class on li items.

Comment: An image of the desired result can really help to solve efficiently your question...

Comment: Example with 2 scripts:

Comment: <li class="col-lg-3"></li><li class="col-lg-3"></li><li class="col-lg-3"></li>

Comment: i want to 9/12 col in the center instead of align left

Comment: i have found the solution ^^ at the address http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this to center your text alignment center

```
<ul class="row">
<li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">text</li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">text</li>
 ..
</ul>
```

or to align columns can use offsets check documentation
    http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Comment: how can i offsets automatic? Because i don't known how many li tag.

Comment: here are solution http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns